# remote shell to and from server core. So I can "dir"

Tags: shell, remote-access

What are the prerequisites for `\\serverNameOrServerAddress\C$` to work in Cmd?

So I can catch a file for my firewall in server core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cmd.exe shell itself does not support UNC paths as current working directories, *but*, many command-line based tools, such as robocopy, definitely do support UNC paths.

Powershell on the other hand, *does* support UNC paths as working directories. (e.g. `cd \\server01\c$\`)

Secondly, you referenced an *Administrative Share* in your question: `C$`. That is called an Administrative Share, and you need administrative access to the remote computer in order to access it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share

Also I'm not sure what you mean by *"so I can catch a file for my firewall in server core,"* but if you want to transfer files to and from a share over the network, you will need name resolution and TCP and UDP port 445. (Direct-hosted SMB over port 445; you can do it without the NetBIOS ports 135 and 137.)

Comment: So I just open these ports in the firewall? What I try to accomplish is to move an exported file of windows firewall settings to a virtual server core box! Thank you!

Comment: Yes all firewalls between you and the remote computer need port 445 open. Something like `C:\>robocopy C:\folder \\server01\c$\ export.txt` will do the trick.